# Minimal circuit for the FE1.1 USB HUB IC

Tags: circuit-design, usb, usb-hub

I have a board with 4 MCU in it, since i dont have the space to have 4 usb ports on the board i opted to include a usb hub circuit. I have read that the [FE1.1](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303171730_Terminus-Tech-FE1-1S-BSOP28BCN_C9359.pdf) is a cheap IC and requires very few components which is perfect with the limited space i have.

The datasheet does not really show a minimal circuit but here is my circuit attempt. 3v3 power for the whole board is supplied by an LDO, So i wont be using the FE1.1 built in regulators.

[image]

Here are my concerns for the circuit.

- XRSTJ,VBUSM,BUSJ,OVCJ are considered by the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303171730_Terminus-Tech-FE1-1S-BSOP28BCN_C9359.pdf#page=8) as schmitt-trigger Inputs, so can i omitt the pull up/down resistors and tie them directly to 3v3/gnd?
- OVCJ is an active low input pin for an external sensor for overcurrent detection, i do not need this as Hub will not power anything. I am not sure where to connect this though, does active low means over current? Hence i should tie it to 3v3?
- Am i missing something ? A component or perhaps a pin connection that is connected wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, having a schmitt trigger input or not does not change in any way if you can directly connect a pin to VCC or GND.
2. Yes, datasheet is clear on this, active low indicates overcurrent.
3. Yes, many pins are left unconnected against datasheet suggestions.

Comment: Where do i connect those pins, the only pins that im aware that i left unnconnected are the OVCJ which will be tied to 3v3, VDD5 which should be left hanging since im using extenal 3v3, and i guess VD3.3F im not using the 3v3 regulator, but i guess i should still place one? I forgot to ask what PWRJ is for, it says its an open drain output signal for power enabling power to the downstream devices, but i dont think i will be needing it so i left it hangging. The only thing left are the LED pins i wont be needing those the datasheet say they can be omitted but does not say if it can be left open